# Sorting not working in solr via solr php client

Tags: solr

Iam using solr php client and this is my query this is how iam writing it

```
$querynew=("(business_name:*$data* OR city_name:$data~N*) sort:business_points desc");
```

Iam passing this into the url
If i remove the sort part it works fine ,but sorting is not working.Iam not abe to figure this out.
Iam new to solr please advise and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about `solr-php-client`, the sort parameter can be supplied using the `$additionalParameters` argument when calling `->search()`.

```
$solr->search($querynew, 0, 10, array(
    'sort' => 'business_points desc',
));
```